# How to fetch price and size of product from any ecommerce website Using Curl PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, curl

I wants to fetch Price and Size from Any ecommerce website using Product page URL
I am writing here my code in which you can see how i am fetching image from any website.

```
<?php
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
   //$ch = curl_init();
$options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false     // Disabled SSL Cert checks
    );

    $ch      = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close($ch);

    return $content;


}
//http://www.ralphlauren.com/product/index.jsp?productId=102437456
//https://www.amazon.com/U-S-Polo-Assn-Tyra-Fashion/dp/B01KY73PKU
//http://www.6pm.com/p/cole-haan-benson-camera-bag-ivory/product/8877280/color/422
//https://www.daraz.pk/prime-black-mens-slim-fit-leather-jacket-t11-5437633.html
$html = file_get_contents_curl("http://www.6pm.com/p/cole-haan-benson-camera-bag-ivory/product/8877280/color/422");

?>

<div style='display:none'><?php echo $html;?></div>

<?php



//parsing begins here:
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

//get and display what you need:
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');
$keywords = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
{
$meta = $metas->item($i);
if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description'){
$description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
}
$prop = $meta->getAttribute('property');
if($prop === 'og:image'){
    $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    if($keywords != '' ){?>
    <input id="ogImg" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $keywords; ?>" /> 
<?php


       }
    }

 }

echo "Title: $title". '<br/><br/>';
//echo "Description: $description". '<br/><br/>';
$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++) {
 echo $hi = $items->item($i)->getAttribute('id') ;
 $bye =  $items->item($i)->getAttribute('src') ;
//$hi= str_replace(' ','',$hi);
//echo gettype($hi).'type<br>';
        if($hi !== ''){
            //var_dump($items->item($i)->getAttribute('id'));
            $newid = $hi;
            ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $bye; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" id="myid" value="<?php echo $hi ?>" />

            <?php 

            break;
        }
// var_dump($items->item($i));
}
?>
<style type="text/css">

    #imgFetch img{
        border: 1px solid grey;
        padding: 3px;
        border-radius:10px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){ 

    var myval = $('#myid').val();
    if(myval !== undefined )
    var elem = $('#'+myval).get(0).outerHTML;
    var ogImg = $('#ogImg').val();
    if(ogImg !== undefined ){
        src = ogImg;
    }else{
    var src =  document.getElementById(myval).src;
    }
    $('body').append('<div id="imgFetch"><img  src="'+src+'" /></div>');
    $('#imgFetch img').css('width','150px');
    $('#imgFetch img').css('height','130px');

    }, 0000);


</script>
```

what i am doing here is getting whole HTML in $html and echo also I am getting image object by using getElementByTagName function, I have got the image correctly and it works on any website url.But the problem is, I am not sure that how can i target price and size given with that image.I wants to grab whole ul element or select element if the price and size are in select element.So please tell me if there is any workaround.

Comment: I have searched the whole google and I am pretty sure that there is nothing on google regarding this topic.Not a single tutorial .

Comment: Requesting a solution for **any** website is very ambitious. But maybe we can help if you could narrow down your question to **one** example you have a problem with. Please [see here how to create a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your question.

Comment: Thanks but i have inserted the whole code here for ease.If anyone can know how it works then he just put this as php file and run it to see my result.

Comment: Also you can see the result i want on this url https://sa.edfa3ly.co/cart . Paste any link url i provided in the code and see the result.How this website is fetching data.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the HTML elements using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, go through this http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: How can I target each website.Simple Dom parser makes array but how can i target each url to get the desired result.